# Simple characteristics problem : Find $b/a$ from $au_{x} + bu_{y} = 0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, characteristics

> suppose that **any** solution $u(x,y)$ to
> $$ au_{x} + b u_{y} = 0,$$
> satisfies $u(1,2) = u(3,6)$. What is $b/a$?

$$au_{x} + bu_{y} = \nabla u \cdot \binom{a}{b} = 0, $$
which implies that $u$ is constant along lines of the form $bx- ay =c \ 
 \ \forall  \ c \in \mathbb{R}$. Therefore the solution is
$$ u(x,t) = g(bx - ay) , \qquad  \text{for  } g  \text{ arbitrary and } \  g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}.$$
\begin{align} 
\because u(1,2) = u(3,6) &\implies g(b-2a) = g(3b-6a), \\
&\implies  b-2a = 3b -6a \tag{1}\\
&\therefore \frac{b}{a} = 2\end{align}

I'm quite confused about how to justify $(1)$, I note that $b-2a$ is a linear combination of $3b-6a$  but I also know that for instance $f(x) = x^{2}$ we have $f(2)  =f(-2) \nRightarrow 2=-2 $. Any insights ?

Comment: $g$ is arbitraray. Just choose $g(x)=x$?

Comment: @ArcticChar Right I see, so to say that $g$ is arbitrary is sufficient to imply that $b-2a = 3b-6a$, i.e., the arguments are equal. Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1):

$$au_x+bu_y=0$$
The general solution is straightaway found thanks to the method of characteristics :
$$u(x,y)=F(bx-ay)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.

$$u(1,2)=u(3,6)\quad\implies\quad F(b-2a)=F(3b-6a)$$
Let $X=b-2a$
$$F(X)=F(3X)$$
Since this equality must be satisfied for all above solutions $u(x,y)$ , that is for all functions $F(X)$ thus :
$$F(X)=F(3X)\quad\implies\quad X=0$$
$$b-2a=0$$
$$\frac{b}{a}=2$$